# lost connection mysql in C

Tags: mysql, c, multithreading

I've written a C program thats running multiple threads and uses MySQL. After some testing i repeatedly saw the error (with hours between) "Mysql server gone away", so i maximized the wait_timeout setting of mysql. But now i get the error "Lost connection to MySQL server during query". These errors only occured when i run the program on a multiple core processor.

Maybe you guys know whats wrong or what i have to do to run my threaded program?

Comment: Doesn't make sense.. When a program is mutithreaded, it is multithreaded, this does not depend on how many cores you CPU has (there are differences in the performance, of course, but this is not the point here). Give us more information, some source, etc.

Comment: I agree, I only told the timeout error occured when I changed the hardware. My was told that the problem lies with mysql, that I have to compile my program with the enable-multthreading or something like that. The code is a simple db connect with a loop thats doing some queries, with some time between.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a multithreaded program that behaves differently on a 1-core system and a multicore system (works on 1-core and has bugs on multicore), it's written incorrectly: that's a sure sign of a race condition.  It means the code is actually incorrect, and if scheduled just wrong will trample on its own data, and this is actually happening in practice on the multicore system and not on the 1-core system.

Actually, the same problem could happen on the 1-core system too, it's just less likely and more rare because the threads can't be scheduled truly simultaneously, so one thread has to preempt the other at just the wrong time, for you to see the buggy behavior.  This is why if you're writing multithreaded code, you should always test and debug it on a multicore host.  You're much more likely to actually see the evidence of race conditions; running on a 1-core host they can remain hidden for much longer.

I don't know what libraries you're using, but they don't look thread-safe or you're not using them in a thread-safe fashion.

Comment: thx for the reply.
the problem seems to be resolved with compiling it with mysqlclient_r.